# Populating a data frame from another data frame that in which some values match

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data frame in which specific columns and some headers match with the headers of a recently created data frame (I show both below). I want to extract data from the large data frame and populate the new one according to the matches.

The large data frame :

```
print(complete_df.head(2))
Unnamed: 0_x_x  #_x_x                Coin  Price_x_x  1h_x  24h_x   7d_x  \
0             NaN      1   Bitcoin  BTC  BTC    $61,700  1.7%   8.8%  25.7%   
1             NaN      2  Ethereum  ETH  ETH  $1,942.39  0.9%  11.5%  26.2%   


      24h Volume_x           Mkt Cap_x  Last 7 Days_x  ...  \
0  $66,511,145,853  $1,147,780,011,087            NaN  ...   
1  $32,515,724,095    $223,366,485,336            NaN  ...   

   Twitter Followers_y  Unnamed: 0_y_y #_y_y  Price_y_y  All-Time High Price  \
0                  NaN             NaN     1    $61,700              $61,533   
1                  NaN             NaN     2  $1,942.73            $2,042.93   

   Since All-Time High      All-Time High Date  Vol/Mcap Market Cap Dominance  \
0                 0.0%  Mar 13, 2021 5 minutes    0.0578               60.59%   
1                -5.0%    Feb 20, 2021 21 days    0.1451               11.79%   

   COIN  
0   BTC  
1   ETH
```

The recently create data frame is empty and only contained the header as shown below

```
print(new)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Time, BTC_Price_x_x, BTC_Mkt Cap_x, BTC_24h Volume_x, BTC_Contributors_x, BTC_Commits in Last 4 Weeks_x, BTC_Reddit Subscribers_x, BTC_FB Likes_x, BTC_Market Cap Dominance, ETH_Price_x_x, ETH_Mkt Cap_x,...]
```

Can you see how the header of the new data frame is the combination of the values contained in the last column (COIN) of the  `complete_df + '_' + 'some headers of the complete_df '` data frame? For example, first header of new data frame is `BTC_Price_x_x = BTC+ '_' + Price_x_x`.

What I want is to populate the new data frame with its corresponding value

```
Time      BTC_Price_x_x  BTC_Mkt Cap_x        BTC_24h Volume_x   ...  ETH_Price_x_x ...        
Index     $61,700        $1,147,780,011,087   $66,511,145,853    ...  $1,942.39     ...
```

Comment: You can use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: I thought that but they are not exactly the same values. What do you mean?

Comment: You can merge the dataframes on one or more relevant columns (eg. Time), and then drop the redundant columns